# iOS: Issue Importing Calls From Another File

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mopub

I'm still new to Objective-C so I'm having a hard time with this. In my AppController, When a user clicks on one of the ads in my app, then closes the ad and returns to my app, I would like to destroy and recreate the ad (Long story as to why). For some reason though, my code isn't working. There are no errors or warnings, but it doesn't do what I intended it to do. This is what my code looks like:

`#import "MoPubManager.h"`

......

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    MoPubManager *obj = [[MoPubManager alloc] init];

    if( obj.adView ) {
        [[MoPubManager sharedManager] destroyBanner];
    }
    [obj.adView refreshAd];

}
```

_adView, destroy banner, and refresh ad are both in the MoPubManager file, so as you can see I imported the file and turned MoPubManager into an object. (obj.adView was originally just _adView in MoPubManager.h, but I had to switch it to obj.adView to avoid warnings.) I may just be using the wrong calls, I would post the MoPubManager.mm file where the calls originally are but its a full page or two

Comment: [MoPubManager sharedManager] ..  are using singleton design pattern ?

Comment: @Malek_Jundi I'm unsure, sorry I'm still very new to this.

Comment: i mean in shareManager are you define a static object ? its better  to show us what are you doing inside shareManager so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
MoPubManager *obj = [[MoPubManager alloc] init];
```

You are creating a **new** instance of the MoPubManager class.

Next you are checking whether the adView property of that newly instantiated class is not nil. Unless adView gets populated in the init method of MoPubManager, this will always be nil, so the destroyBanner method will not be called.

However, the destroyBanner method is being called on a sharedManager... indicating a singleton pattern in use. Therefore you should not be creating a new instance as this goes against the reason for using a singleton. (You only ever have one instance of a class when using a singleton - see [this for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern))

Without seeing more code, it seems that you should be calling something like:

```
if( [MoPubManager sharedManager].adView ) {
    [[MoPubManager sharedManager] destroyBanner];
}
[[MoPubManager sharedManager].adView refreshAd];
```

Answer (score 1):

First, what subclass is MoPubManager... It compiles fine? The problem here seems to be that you are creating a new MoPubManager instance, but you are using a singleton to destroy it, and they don't have the same reference. You should use something diferent like:

```
MoPubManager *obj = [[MoPubManager alloc] init];

if( [MoPubManager sharedManager].adView ) {

    [[MoPubManager sharedManager] destroyBanner];
}
[[MoPubManager sharedManager].adView refreshAd];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using correctly the singleton pattern.

try this , maybe will help you

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    MoPubManager *obj = [MoPubManager sharedManager];

    if( obj.adView ) {
        [obj destroyBanner];
    }
    [obj.adView refreshAd];
}
```